# xml java xslt tag

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a java code snippet:

```
public static String echo(String a) {
    System.out.println("HERE I AM:"+a+":");
    return "<xxx>" + a + "</xxx>";
}
```

called by the below xsl snippet:

```
<GOGO>
     <xsl:variable name="test">
        <xsl:copy-of select="responseStatus"/>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:copy-of select="javamap:echo($test)"/>
</GOGO>
```

For some reason if xml is passed to the java method, all the element tags are dropped. on the output side if i try to return xml tags, the < and > would be converted to & lt; and & gt;

What is wrong with my snippet and how can it be fixed so it outputs XML?

EDIT (after 1st response)
Let me elaborate on the problem:

My system out output is below:
HERE I AM:
        val1
        val2
   :

Ideally I would like my system out to be:

`HERE I AM:<foo>val1</foo><bar>val2</bar>:`

as you can see, the xml tags are being dropped for some reason.

here is the solution I came up with:

```
public static String echo(Node a) throws Exception {

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(a), new StreamResult(writer));
    String xml = writer.toString();
    return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
<xsl:value-of select="responseStatus" disable-output-escaping="no" />
```

Comment: thank for bring awareness of the disable-output-escaping tag. however my remaining problem is on the input side where i am not able to pass xml to my java class. Let me elaborate on the problem.

Comment: when you say "My system out output", you talk about System.out.println on console or an output in an HTML page ? If on a HTML Page, you should view source to get your "real" textual output.

Comment: "My system out output" refers to System.out.println on console

Comment: I suggest you create XML elements with XSL, not using a String in java code. <xxx><xsl:copy-of select="javamap:echo($test)"/></xxx> or <xsl:element name="xxx"><xsl:copy-of........</xsl:element> but maybe that's not your point...?